# Latex posters - to scale or not to scale

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling, posters

I am designing a rather large poster (850mm x 2150mm) and trying to figure out whether to create it in actual size or whether to create a smaller version and scale it up afterwards.

The two comments under [an answer that recommends scaling up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609/14210) make good points against it:

> I recommend creating the poster in its true size, since that will enable commands like `\vspace{1cm}` to do what's expected. –  Ben Jan 30 '11 at 18:48
>
> Another reason for creating your poster in its original size is that if you use a font with optical scaling, then you will get the correct weight. (Large fonts != small fonts scaled up). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/selecting-optical-size) for example. –  mforbes Dec 8 '11 at 5:42

"this question" is about [optical font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/selecting-optical-size) which implies that fonts are designed for a particular size, so you should always select the correct font size rather than scale another one.

Stephan Lemke, however, [argues the exact opposite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52879/14210), also for optical font size reasons.

So: To scale or not to scale? If I try to use a 32pt font, is that not a scaled up version anyway? Or is it a matter of creating the poster in real size but use all the different font sizes scaled up by the same amount (i.e. redefine `\large` as being \cmr12 at 32pt, for example)?

Comment: No font that I know of has optical size variants for over 17pt; Computer Modern has cmr17, but no other variant, so boldface must be scaled from cmbx10 or cmbx12 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For posters, one usually can not get the print-out from a desktop printer and a special printer is required from printing house. But I would recommend creating LaTeX poster in its true size, because you can then scale it down to A4/A3 size via package `pdfpages` for proofread.  This is how I do when a poster is needed, then use the following code to convert it to A4 size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[turn=false,pages=1]{PosterLarge.pdf} 
\end{document}
```